# How to build AOSP for a device with no modem?

Tags: android-source

I am working on a tablet that has no modem (aka cellular radio) and is not designed to be used for receiving or sending voice calls/SMS/MMS using cdma/gsm/etc, it does however have Wi-Fi. This device unfortunately is based on a device that does have a modem. I wonder if anyone has a complete list of changes that need to be made to the android platform for a devices like this? I am working on Nougat. Here's what I have so far:

- switched my device mk file to point to full_base.mk instead of full_base_telephony.mk
- added a overlay/frameworks/base/care/res/res/values/config.xml with config_voice_capable set to false, config_sms_capable set to false, config_telephonyHardware set to an empty string array
- set PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTICS := tablet in my device mk file
- copy tablet_core_hardware.xml to system/etc/permissions instead of handheld_core_hardware.xml
- set ro.radio.noril property to true, comment out service ril-daemon and any ims service from any init rc files

Am I missing anything?

Some things I noticed are the following modules are still included in the system image: BlockedNumberProvider, Telecom, TeleService, MmsService, TelephonyProvider, voip-common.jar, telecom.jar, telephony-common.jar, ims-common.jar. Even though I have selected the "no telephony" build mk files. Are these modules all needed on a device that doesn't have telephony features? As an experiment I removed the APKs (I haven't tried remove the jars yet) and the device seems to boot and run just fine so it seems they are just wasting resources.

Comment: I also work on a product that lacks telephony; it functions without the BlockedNumberProvider, Telecom, TeleService, MmsService apks, which I purposely exclude. Your build is probably picking these up by using full_base_telephony.mk which includes build/target/product/core.mk (which adds these unwanted modules into its PRODUCT_PACAKGES variable).